# Re-render component when pathname changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

yo guys I m having little problem 
my components doesnt rerender on pathname changing I tried everything but still not managed to work here is useEffect func

```
useEffect(() => {
    var user=window.location.pathname.replace('/user/','');
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://rating.test';
 axios.get('/api/getuser',{headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('userToken')}` },params:{username: user,}}).then(res=>{
      setposts(res.data.posts);
      setuser({id:res.data.id,username:res.data.username});
  })


 },[window.location.pathname])
```

I m using react router btw

EDIT : my router

```
    <Router>
   <MyHeader />
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
<Route path="/main" >
  <Main/>
</Route>
<Route path="/myposts" >
  <Profile/>
</Route>
<Route path="/user/:id" >
  <User />
</Route>
```

Comment: You don't need to put `window.location.pathname` because when the url will change then  react will automatically rerender all of the components from that matched route. So the `useEffect` will be called. You have problem with your components structure i think.

Comment: @HMR thanks for the useparams  didnt know about it,now  I put it on state but the problem is the state doesnt update even when the url changes , how can I update it ?

Comment: @HMR no it doesnt get called in the second time

Comment: @HMR no it doesnt it always stays on the first state and I removed the window.location

Comment: @chenten Your problem is with the router, if the component is not rendering at all after a route change and having the useParams in that component.

Comment: @HMR I posted my router take a look (I m putting it on app,js)